# jQuery setTimeout on Append

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a timeout on the following append method in jQuery. Everything I've tried keeps returning `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Here is my code:

```
    setTimeout("$('#user-comments').append('<div class='video_comment'>
<div class='name'>David</div><div class='time'>test</div>
<div class='indiv-comment'><p>'"+message+"'</p></div></div><hr class='gray' />')",3000);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#user-comments").append('<div class="video_comment">
                                <div class="name">David</div>
                                <div class="time"><?php echo date('F j, Y, g:i a'); ?></div>
                                <div class="indiv-comment"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div>');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I've edited my original code taking out the PHP and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, linebreaks can be a big bother in javascript. And as Neil stated, you need to escape your quotation marks. Sometimes breaking up a longer string makes it a lot more readable. Also, you can supply a function to setTimeout instead of a string. Here's an example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var nameTag = '<div class="name">David</div>';
    var timeTag = '<div class="time">test</div>';
    var commentTag = '<div class="indiv-comment"><p>' + message + '</p></div>';
    var wrap = '<div class="video_comment">' +
                   nameTag +
                   timeTag +
                   commentTag +
               '</div><hr class="gray" />';

    $('#user-comments').append(wrap)
}, 3000);
```

This way, you can clearly see which quotation marks start and end where, and you won't have to bother with linebreaks within the string at all.